# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink

Tags: node.js, fs

As you can see, there is a file at the path. But fs says no such file or directory. I can't understand why?

In another file, I can remove with the same code.

My boat.js file:

```
boat.findById(req.params.id,function(err, foundBoat) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        foundBoat.boatsFoto.forEach(function(path){
            console.log(typeof(path));
            fs.unlink("../public"+path,function(err){
                if(err) throw err;

                console.log('File deleted!');
            });
        });
    } 
});
```

And it is my error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink '../public/uploads/akingokay/BoatsFoto/1524411110335kiralik-tekne.jpg'
at Error (native)
```

[And you can see my file system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRjf0.png)

Comment: Use `path` module for creating paths, I think this solve your problem

Comment: Hi @Saeed.At,

How can i use path module for this operation. Actually, How will it give me an advantage?

Comment: Add a `console.log(path.normalize("../public"+path))` right before your `unlink()` call to see what the fully resolved path actually is.  Probably the `../` isn't doing what you thought it was.  Remember, `../` is relative to the current directory, not to the module directory.

Comment: hi @jfriend00,

I added console.log(path.normalize("../public"+path)) before my unlink().

And output is:  ../public/uploads/akingokay/BoatsFoto/1524411110335kiralik-tekne.jpg and ../public/uploads/akingokay/BoatsFoto/1524411110617sirenayachts64-1.jpg on terminal. Actually same with "../public"+path.

Comment: Hmmm, weird.  I thought it would resolve the `..` into an absolute path so you could see exactly what it's look for.  Maybe try `path.resolve()` instead of `path.normalize()`.

Comment: And where in the file system is the js file you start with node? How does the command look like with that you load that file? Node tries to resolve  the `../public` path according to the cwd and not to the file in which you call `unlink`, cwd is normally the directory in which the file is that you execute with node.

Comment: Thank you all,

shubhambharti201's answer worked for me. I accepted shubhambharti201's answer. 

thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can you try this instead:

```
fs.unlink("public"+path,function(err){
    if(err) throw err;

    console.log('File deleted!');
});
```

Comment: Hi @shubhambharti201, 

this worked !! But why ? Can you explain ?  Why I shouldn't use "../" ?

Comment: In loopback (nodejs framework), the main directory where the node_modules/ lies, is taken as the reference directory. And "../" means you are going out of that main project directory.

Answer (score 4):

You should first install the `path` module via CLI:

```
npm install path --save
```

and use it:

```
fs.unlink(path.join("public/" + path, photo.id + ".jpg"), function(response) {
  // handle the callback
});
```

Comment: your solution is helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if  the path variable you are adding to the "/public" has a "/" at the beginning. If there is no/ seperating it it will treat the path as one.

Comment: thank you for your comment, but string in path variable begining with /. Actually, path in error is right path and exist.

Answer (score 0):

Install and import `path` module. this helps you https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Instead of `"../public"+path` use `path.join("../", "public", path);`

Comment: Hi, 

thank you for your answer, but @shubhambharti201's answer is worked for me.

thank for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you host the server. If it is on a local machine then you will probably need to specify the complete path to the file(s) that you want to delete or manipulate. If it is on a web server that is live then you will need to specify the complete path to it.

on a "**local machine**" it might look something like this:

```
fs.unlink('/home/user/project/someothername/'+filename, err => {
// handler
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider like you are in `app.js` file and give the relative path of deleting file to the `fs.unlink('path/to/file')`. it will work!